# Redirect any page passing certain variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm putting a search engine on my site, and the search box appears on several different pages.
The output looks like this: http://mysite.com/mypage.php?bluepart=search&keywords=dogs&go=Go
I'm trying to do an .htaccess mod rewrite to where any page that passes these variables will get redirected to search_results.php. The bluepart=search and go=Go will always be the same, but keywords can be any number or words. Also, some of my pages are .html and some are .php, when I refer to any page that passes the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) option. It allows you to specify a rewrite if an regular expression matches the Query string (QUERY_STRING).

Comment: I know how it's done. I don't know how to exactly code these two parts: redirect from any page, and any word or number on the keywords variable.